# How i can get the label of the selected value in Combobox - Lightning Web Components?

Tags: lightning-web-components, label, lightning-combobox

I'm developing a LWC Combobox and I want to get the label of the selected value in the `handleChange()` method, not the `id`. I filled the combobox with JSON Items in this form :

```js
{value :'Id', label:'Label'}
```

I used this in JS : `event.detail.value` but it gives the id not the Label.

Comment: I tried that before but event.detail.label is undefined. I have a solution in my mind which consist of storing all the items (id,label) in an array and as I can get the id of the selected value, I can find the corresponding label from the array,  but this solution is very onerous.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You do not have direct way of getting label (as you get only selected value in `event.detail`). You need to depend on all options (simply get it from `event.target`) and filter based on selected value. You can use below:

JS:

```
@track selectedLabel;

get options() {
    return [
        { label: 'New', value: 'new' },
        { label: 'In Progress', value: 'inProgress' },
        { label: 'Finished', value: 'finished' },
    ];
}

handleChange(event) {
    this.selectedLabel = event.target.options.find(opt => opt.value === event.detail.value).label;
}
```

HTML:

```
<lightning-combobox name="progress"
                        label="Status"
                        placeholder="Select Progress"
                        options={options}
                        onchange={handleChange}></lightning-combobox>

    <p>Selected label is: {selectedLabel}</p>
```

Comment: It works, Thank you @salesforce-sas.

Comment: Yeah, that's correct ^

Answer (score 6):

Another way to get the label, iterate with options and match the value to find the label.

```
   statusOptions = [
        {value: 'new', label: 'New'},
        {value: 'in-progress', label: 'In Progress'},
        {value: 'finished', label: 'Finished'}
    ];

    handleChange(event) {
        const selectedOption = event.detail.value;
        var currentLabel =  this.statusOptions.filter(function(option) {
                               return option.value == selectedOption;
                            })
        if(currentLabel)
          //get the label
          console.log(currentLabel[0].label)

    }
```

Comment: Yeah this works to but i prefer @salesforce-sas is solution. Thank you ^^