# Upon clicking Lightning Combo-box, I want to store Value & Label both?

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components, html

I want to store both Value & Label attribute upon clicking particular Combo-box value, but currently I am only able to get Value.

When I try to store & print Label - it says undefined.

[image]

Here is the [PLAYGROUND LINK](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/_ZDpXiiN/4/edit).

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/278687/how-i-can-get-the-label-of-the-selected-value-in-combobox-lightning-web-compon/278691)

Answer (score 2):

Use below code to fix the issue:

```
handleChange(event) {
        this.value = event.detail.value;
        let selectedObjectlabel  = event.target.options.find(opt => opt.value === event.detail.value).label;
        console.log('Label ->' + selectedObjectlabel);
    }
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For value attribute store values in JSON String format
Like { label: 'New', value: '{"label" : "New", "value":"1"}' }

In handleChange Method convert JSON String to object and access label and value properties of that object.

Code Snippet.

basic.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-combobox
            name="progress"
            value={value}
            placeholder="Select"
            options={options}
            onchange={handleChange} ></lightning-combobox>

    <p>Selected value is: {value}</p>
</template>
```

basic.js

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class ComboboxBasic extends LightningElement {
    @track value = 'inProgress';

    get options() {
        return [
            { label: 'New', value: '{"label" : "New", "value":"1"}' },
            { label: 'In Progress', value: '{"label" : "In Progress", "value":"2"}' },
            { label: 'Finished', value: '{"label" : "Finished", "value":"3"}' },
        ];
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        let v = JSON.parse(event.detail.value);
        console.log('Label - ' + v.label);
        this.value = v.value;
    }
}
```

Playground link - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/x0iNRAPJ/1/edit

Comment: That's extremely complicated and overkill. There are better ways to handle this (see the other answers).